# Sprint Cumulative Flow Diagram

Tags: scrum, diagram

Can anyone give me some tips about how to read a Cumulative Flow Diagram. I'm not sure what kind of things its telling me.

Comment: I just wrote a blog article called [Cumulative Flow Diagrams with Google Spreadsheets](http://open.bekk.no/2009/11/03/cumulative-flow-diagrams-with-google-spreadsheets/) that might help.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)